# Facebook Login with LoginManager loginWithPublishPermissions not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to Integrate Facebook Android SDK in my Android App. I have used this block to allow users to Login.`

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    //some more code
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_UPDATE;
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OnSuccess for RegisterCallback");

                    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains(PERMISSION)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "I want to  Post on Facebook");
                        postStatusUpdate("Hello World Post!");
                        updateUI();

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "I want more permissions");
                        requestPublishPermissions();
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OnCancel for RegisterCallback");
                    if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                        showAlert();
                        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                    }
                    updateUI();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OnError for RegisterCallback");
                    if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                            && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                        showAlert();
                        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                    }
                    updateUI();
                }

                private void showAlert() {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ShareFacebookActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                            .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        requestPublishPermissions();
```

`
As you can see that most code has been copied from [Facebook Sample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/example/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java)

I am trying to Login with Publish Permissions but when user enters Username / Password , it shows screen as if I haven't added Publish permissions. It shows the message "This doesn't allow app to post on Facebook."

When I try to add publish permissions, using this code

```
LoginManager.getInstance()
                .setDefaultAudience(DefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));
```

It shows that you have already authorized this app.
What should I do? Please comment before down-voting .

Comment: Does the HelloFacebookSample code work? if so, then you should be able to see what's missing in your project that is preventing this from working properly. The code you provided doesn't really give much of info for people to help

Comment: What else code you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check if you already have the permission to post on user behalf.. something like this..

```
    final Bundle permBundle = new Bundle();
    permBundle.putCharSequence("permission", "publish_actions");
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/permissions", permBundle, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response2: " + graphResponse.getJSONObject());
                    try {
                        JSONArray permList = (JSONArray) graphResponse.getJSONObject().get("data");
                        if(permList.length() == 0){
                            // no data for perms, hence asking permission
                            askForFBPublishPerm();
                        }else{
                            JSONObject permData = (JSONObject) permList.get(0);
                            String permVal = (String) permData.get("status");
                            if(permVal.equals("granted")){
                                postToFB();
                            }else{
                                askForFBPublishPerm();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "exception while parsing fb check perm data" + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Error occurred while connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    request.executeAsync();
```

In case you need to ask the permission, use the below snippet

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
void askForFBPublishPerm(){
    Log.d(TAG, "asking for the permissions");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
            PreviewActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            postToFB();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancelled while asking publish permission");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error occurred while asking publish permission!");
        }
    });
}
```